# Debugging with IronPython Tools in Visual Studio Shell: can't watch the variables

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, ironpython

I've installed VS 2010 Shell and IronPython Tools, but I can't get the debugger to show any values via Quick Watch, it says variable is not found in the context. Is it because I don't have VS 2010 itself installed, only the shell? The IronPython Tools Walkthrough document says debugging is so far only supported via C# expression evaluator.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

This is because it's supported via the C# expression evaluator.  Therefore the locals you see are the locals that C# sees.  If you are inside of a function then generally the parameters and locals should be available as variables in watch/locals/autos.  They're probably not available if you call locals(), use exec/eval, or they're closure variables.  They're also probably unavailable in a global or class context.  Usually there will be other variables (usually starting with a $) which you can use to dig out the actual values.

If you don't need debugging between C# (or other .NET languages) and IronPython you could actually use the new "[Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com)" which has a pure-Python debugging mode which works with IronPython.  You'll need to uninstall the IronPython tools feature in IronPython 2.7 first though.

Comment: Thank you, you're exactly right. I am able to view locals and also drill down from $-variables to global variables.

Comment: However I don't seem to be able to run a simple .py program that imports another .py file and calls a function from there. I get IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException. Needless to say, it all works OK with pure ipy.exe, without VS. I understand the second file is not properly imported into the first one. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are your python scripts in the same project folder? (f.e. /bin/debug)
Otherwise you need to add the path of your scripts/libary/... to your python-engine ---> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735642/import-python-module-through-c-sharp-net-using-ironpython/12737175)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the project properties and change the  "Launch Mode" to "Standard Python Launcher" (unless you need to debug C# code)