# Import Python Module through C# .NET using IronPython

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, nltk

I am trying to run a Python class through C# .NET using IronPython, a couple of the Modules imported by the Python class are:

```
import collections
import nltk.classify.util
```

In order to import these when running IronPython, I am using the **GetSearchPath** collection of the **ScriptEngine** to add the path to the location of the Python library, as such:

```
ICollection<string> paths = pyEngine.GetSearchPaths();
string dir = @"C:\Python27\Lib\";
paths.Add(dir);
string dir2 = @"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\";
paths.Add(dir2);
pyEngine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
```

This seems to run fine for the **collections** Module, but not the **nltk.classify.util**, and I get the following error when calling the Execute method of the ScriptEngine:

**No module named nltk.classify.util**

Even tho the util module lives in the path specified above. I take it the issue has to do with the way the import is specified in the Python class ('.' delimited), just not sure how to solve it. Any ideas where am going wrong?

Comment: ToOsIK, can you show how do you import modules into Python engine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python uses the structure of a package name to search for a module, so if you ask for `nltk.classify.util` it will look for `nltk\classify\util.py` starting from each directory in the search path.

So in your example, you want to change `dir2` as follows:

```
string dir2 = @"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages";
```