# Calling script.py from c# with process but getting error import modules like cv2

Tags: c#, python, opencv

I'm writing some python code include open-cv. And now ı have to add some UI and ım using c# but when ı try to call.py

ı tried to use the process to call my .py file

```
string python = @"C:\Windows.old\Users\giris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe";

            string myPythonApp = "C://Users//giris//Desktop//staj_proje_son//main.py";

            string ogrencioptik = textBox2.Text;
            string cevapkagidi = textBox1.Text;
            ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(python);

            myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + ogrencioptik + " " + cevapkagidi;
            Process myProcess = new Process();
            myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

            myProcess.Start();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
            string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
            myProcess.WaitForExit();
            myProcess.Close();
```

Python file must work fine and it must write the results to a .txt file.

here is the error:

```
File "C://Users//giris//Desktop//staj_proje_son//main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added python to path, you can instead of calling process on python, call it on cmd (assuming you are running on Windows), as you would run python script from cmd: "python .../myscript.py args"

```
string cmdArguments = "/c \"python " + myApp+ " " + sScriptARGS + "\"";

        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        start.Arguments = cmdArguments;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;// Any output, generated by application will be redirected back
        start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)
        using(Process process = Process.Start(start)){...}
```

Or you could try using Microsoft.Hosting.Scripting with IronPython. :) good luck

Comment: Also, if you want to use IronPython, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12735642/import-python-module-through-c-sharp-net-using-ironpython

Comment: Sorry its didnt work the terminal showing up but program is not working and cmd is closing in 1-2 sec

Comment: Yeah the terminal closes as evrything is finished. There might still be a problem. You can try redirecting the output to a file and check if the error persists. What about just running your python file in cmd? Just cmd, without C# and everything? Does your program work?